# In which scene is the White Van in Braveheart?

Tags: braveheart, production-mistakes

I've heard many rumors of the infamous movie mistake - the white van, visible in the background of one of the battle scenes in Braveheart.  However I've never spotted it.  Does anyone have a time code or key identifying moment and quadrant of screen to look for the van?

Comment: While I understand the fun in this question, I hope we're not going to hold this kind of question for every movie that has errors like these in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The scene is the second "goof" of this [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OQx7BFo9fvA) video:

Answer (score 6):

It's a bit different to Seanland's answer, but [this site](http://www.moviemistakes.com/film207/page1) gives a couple of instances (both on the first page).

> Visible crew/equipment: At the funeral of William Wallace's wife, Murron, a white van can be seen. He bends down to kiss her and as he stands back up, if you look over his left shoulder through the trees you can see the van going past. It's very quick, small, and blurred, but it's there.

It's not during a battle scene like you asked, but (apparently) it is van and not a car.

> Revealing: When Wallace walks up to the man who killed Murron and faces him. Look at the man behind Wallace and the man. You can actually see a car passing behind his head in the distance.

I don't have any timecodes or video links to check the accuracy of these things (or the site in general) but you should be able to find the scenes from the descriptions.

Comment: I want to accept both, but can only give you a vote.  Thanks for the extra searching!

Comment: @MarkMayo No worries :) I can't beat video evidence :)